# Thymeleaf table displays null values for some columns but they are not empty in the console

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I trying to display record in from a database in thymeleaf table in a specific format and some of the shows null value. I try to print the data in the console which show that the record is not empty and I need some help to fix it. Below is sample of the code

controller class

```
@GetMapping("/timetable")
public String listTimeTable(Model model) {
    List<TimeTable> timeTableRecords = timeTableService.listTimeTable();

    // Create a map to store the table data
    Map<Subject, Map<WeekDays, TimeTable>> tableData = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (TimeTable record : timeTableRecords) {
        Subject subject = record.getSubject();
        WeekDays day = record.getDay();

        // Check if the subject already exists in the map
        if (!tableData.containsKey(subject)) {
            // Create a new inner map for the subject
            tableData.put(subject, new LinkedHashMap<>());
            
        }

        // Check if the day already exists in the inner map
        if (!tableData.get(subject).containsKey(day)) {
            // Add the record to the inner map
            tableData.get(subject).put(day, record);
            System.out.println("List Table Data: " + tableData);
        }
    }

    model.addAttribute("tableData", tableData);
    return "timetable/timetable";
}
```

System.out.println("List Table Data: " + tableData); this below record in the console

```
List Table Data: {Subject [name=Mathematics, code=M101, subjectType=Theory]={Monday=TimeTable [day=Monday, startTime=23:15, endTime=12:16, roomNumber=78, subject=Mathematics, lectureroom=Class 1, section=A]}}
```

List Table Data: {Subject [name=Mathematics, code=M101, subjectType=Theory]={Monday=TimeTable [day=Monday, startTime=23:15, endTime=12:16, roomNumber=78, subject=Mathematics, lectureroom=Class 1, section=A], Tuesday=TimeTable [day=Tuesday, startTime=12:15, endTime=14:15, roomNumber=56, subject=Mathematics, lectureroom=Class 1, section=A]}}
List Table Data: {Subject [name=Mathematics, code=M101, subjectType=Theory]={Monday=TimeTable [day=Monday, startTime=23:15, endTime=12:16, roomNumber=78, subject=Mathematics, lectureroom=Class 1, section=A], Tuesday=TimeTable [day=Tuesday, startTime=12:15, endTime=14:15, roomNumber=56, subject=Mathematics, lectureroom=Class 1, section=A], Wednesday=TimeTable [day=Wednesday, startTime=12:15, endTime=13:16, roomNumber=35, subject=Mathematics, lectureroom=Class 1, section=A]}}
List Table Data: {Subject [name=Mathematics, code=M101, subjectType=Theory]={Monday=TimeTable [day=Monday, startTime=23:15, endTime=12:16, roomNumber=78, subject=Mathematics, lectureroom=Class 1, section=A], Tuesday=TimeTable [day=Tuesday, startTime=12:15, endTime=14:15, roomNumber=56, subject=Mathematics, lectureroom=Class 1, section=A], Wednesday=TimeTable [day=Wednesday, startTime=12:15, endTime=13:16, roomNumber=35, subject=Mathematics, lectureroom=Class 1, section=A], Thursday=TimeTable [day=Thursday, startTime=13:17, endTime=12:17, roomNumber=65, subject=Mathematics, lectureroom=Class 1, section=A]}} ...

but when I try to display it the table i get null values for startTime, endTime and roomNumber

this is a sample of the thymeleaf table code

```html
<div class="card card-body">
        <table class="table  table-striped table-hover table-responsive-sm align-middle" id="tableRefresh">
            <thead class="table-dark text-center">
               <tr>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
                <th>Saturday</th>
                <th>Sunday</th>
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr th:each="listrecord : ${tableData}">
            <!-- Subject column -->
            <td th:text="${listrecord.key.name}"></td>

            <!-- Weekday columns -->
            <td th:each="day : ${T(com.sch.common.entity.WeekDays).values()}"
                th:text="${listrecord.value[day]?.startTime} + ' - ' + ${listrecord.value[day]?.endTime} + ' ' + ${listrecord.value[day]?.roomNumber}">
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
    </table>
    
    </div>
```

picture of the database and table

[image: database]
[image: thymleaf table]

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to get what I was trying to achieve. I decided to post the solution here in case someone faces a similar issue.

```
<div class="card card-body">
    <table class="table  table-hover table-responsive-sm align-middle" id="tableRefresh">
        <thead class="table-dark text-center">
           <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
        </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
     <tr th:each="listrecord : ${tableData}">
        <!-- Subject column -->
        <td th:text="${listrecord.key.name}"></td>

        <!-- Weekday columns -->
        <th:block th:each="innerrecord : ${listrecord.value}" >
            <td th:each="day : ${innerrecord.value.day}">
                <div class="col card w-auto" id="cardColor">
                    <div>
                        [[${innerrecord.value.startTime}]] - [[${innerrecord.value.endTime}]]  
                    </div>
                    <div>Room No: [[${innerrecord.value.roomNumber}]]</div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </th:block>
        
    </tr>
    
</tbody>
</table>
```

[image: thymeleaf timetable]